# Java: How to Iterate through table cells to capture number in randomly changing table

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Below is my table structure and I'm using Selenium using Java to iterate through all rows and capture number "`00955222222222`" which will display randomly in any cell. once I get this, I have read entire row and get auth code. I can implement till looping rows and cols. But need input how I can get the auth code? Please help

```html
<table border="2" cellspacing="0" width="100%" cellpadding="0">
  <tr bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
    <td align="left">
      <font face="times new roman" size=3><b>&nbsp;Mobile Number</b></font>
    </td>
    <td align="left">
      <font face="times new roman" size=3><b>&nbsp;Date</b></font>
    </td>
    <td align="left">
      <font face="times new roman" size=3><b>&nbsp;Message</b></font>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr bgcolor="#EBD8B8">
    <td align="left" nowrap>
      <font face="times new roman" size=3>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;955111111111</font>
    </td>
    <td align="left" nowrap>
      <font face="times new roman" size=3>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;2017-03-14 16:57:20.027</font>
    </td>
    <td align="left">
      <font face="times new roman" size=3>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Your authentication code is: 11292 to transfer INR 5,500.00 through online/mobile banking. If you have not requested any transfer, please contact the bank IMMEDIATELY on 00971 600 54 0000 .</font>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
    <td align="left" nowrap>
      <font face="times new roman" size=3>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;00955222222222</font>
    </td>
    <td align="left" nowrap>
      <font face="times new roman" size=3>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;2017-03-14 16:55:30.187</font>
    </td>
    <td align="left">
      <font face="times new roman" size=3>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Your authentication code is: 59859 to pay AED 1.00 to Empower through online/mobile banking. Please do not share this code with any person. If you have not requested any payment, please contact the bank IMMEDIATELY on 00971 600
        54 0000 .</font>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr bgcolor="#EBD8B8">
    <td align="left" nowrap>
      <font face="times new roman" size=3>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;00955111111111</font>
    </td>
    <td align="left" nowrap>
      <font face="times new roman" size=3>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;2017-03-14 16:54:46.25</font>
    </td>
    <td align="left">
      <font face="times new roman" size=3>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Your authentication code is: 79404 to transfer PKR 7000 through online/mobile banking. If you have not requested any transfer, please contact the bank IMMEDIATELY on 00971 600 54 0000 .</font>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: find the table and get the "tr" list by using "tagname". Iterate through the "tr" list and get the list of "td". Iterate through the "td" and you get the Authentication code. Have a condition if you just need the Authentication code. Is this what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

I like writing functions for things like this since they are likely to be reused. The function below takes in the mobile number that you are searching for and returns the auth code. The basic logic is grab the TRs and loop through them looking for the one that contains the mobile number. Once you find that TR, use regex to find the auth code from with that TR and return it.

```
public static String GetAuthCode(String mobileNumber)
{
    List<WebElement> rows = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("tr"));
    for (WebElement row : rows)
    {
        String text = row.getText();
        if (text.contains(mobileNumber))
        {
            String regex = "Your authentication code is: (\\d+)";
            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);

            if (matcher.find())
            {
                return matcher.group(1);
            }
        }
    }

    return "not found";
}
```

Comment: ok, JeffC , even I have tried some sample code will copy here. I will try this as well.

Comment: I tried the above code but it is always returning the old auth code but not the recent ones. there are multiple <tr> tags with same number and I need to return the latest one

Comment: What does "latest one" mean?